# Javascript - move all commas in a string to a new position

Tags: javascript, string

in a given string, I want to move all commas at the ends of words in a string to the end of the word before the word they are attached to.
ex: "sometime soon the, cat said let's, go!" would read: "sometime soon, the cat said, let's go!"
any suggestions?

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Changing the question in a way that invalidates all received answers is bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems is easily solved using [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with capturing groups and [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The arguments of `String.replace` are the aforementioned regex and a callback function whose second, third and fourth arguments are the captured groups:

```js
let str = "sometime soon the, cat said let's, go!";
let result = str.replace(/(\s)(\S+)(,)/g, (match, whitespace, word, comma) =>
  comma + whitespace + word
);

console.log(result); // "sometime soon, the cat said, let's go!"
```

I recommend consulting Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) for such questions in the future as it is a valuable resource containing many good examples and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Question was edited, this was an answer to a previous version of it. le_m's answer is a great answer, and I recommend using it.

-

Edit: I thought I'd add a little context regarding what I chose to do here.

Strings in Javascript are immutable, that means they can not be changed, but we can manage to create copies of them as we like. We can then, if we like, assign the new value and override the old variable of course.

As I don't necessarily think in "regex-way", I find it easiest to convert strings to arrays, using split(' '), and mapping over each word using functional map. To map, I pass an arrow function that is responsible for evaluating each word. Once I'm done working on my array, I join it back to a string.

```
let sentence = 'again, the cat said, let's go!'   
let result = sentence.split(' ').map((word) => word[word.length -1] == ',' ? ','+word.substring(0,word.length -1) : word).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with RegExp and `string.replace()`:

```
  str.replace(/(\w*)(,)/g, '$2$1');
```

What this is doing is capturing a line of word characters `\w*` that are succeeded by commas in two separate capture groups. The second parameter actually allows us to reference these capture groups in what we should replace the matched substring with!